# differentiate between linux and windows machine with powershell

Tags: linux, windows, powershell, powershell-3.0, hyper-v

I am running hyperV server which has many Linux and Windows virtual machines. I want to write powershell script which will give me list of windows machines.

command "Get-VM" gives list of all virtual machines.

I have done some research to differentiate between Linux and Windows machines, where i found, windows machines returns version of Operating system where Linux don't do the same.
This is not very efficient, anyone knows any other way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried this script, which is working fine for me.

```
 filter Import-CimXml
  {
   $CimXml = [Xml]$_
  $osNameNode = $CimXml.SelectSingleNode("/INSTANCE/PROPERTY[@NAME='Name']/VALUE[child::text() = 'OSName']")
if ($osNameNode -ne $null)
     {
     return $osNameNode.SelectSingleNode("/INSTANCE/PROPERTY[@NAME='Data']/VALUE/child::text()").Value
} 
}


  $vmList =Get-VM 

  foreach ($vm in $vmList)
   {
     $vmObj = Get-WmiObject -Namespace root\virtualization\v2 -Query "Select * From Msvm_ComputerSystem Where ElementName='$($vm.Name)'"
   $Kvp = $vmObj.GetRelated("Msvm_KvpExchangeComponent")
  $CimData = $Kvp.GuestIntrinsicExchangeItems

     if ($CimData -ne $null) #only for running vm
 {
  $osName = ($CimData | Import-CimXml)
  if ($osName -ne $null) # os like linux or something not supported KVPExchange
    {
    if ($osName.Contains("Window"))
     {
      Write-Host "$($vm.Name)"
     }
   }
} 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

> i have done some research where i found, windows machines returns version of Operating system where Linux don't do the same.

So you need to iterate over your list of VMs, and check each VM's OS version.

By the way, this doesn't sound like a really good way to do this. Who tells you that future updates to Hyper-V will not return a version for linux machines?

Comment: is there any other way you are aware of..??

Comment: I'd just *name* the VMs to reflect what's inside. Other than that, there's a lot going on about introspection into VMs, but that's a current hot topic, and I don't know how Hyper-V deals with that.

Comment: you are not helping man, naming VM for whats inside it, how come it is a solution, i want it for company enterprise product. I cant check name of VM, because VM name can be anything, anyway thanks.

Comment: Sorry, everything like "windows version" is just attached information, exactly like a name. You didn't specify you can't change the name, so that is honestly what I'd do.

Answer (score 0):

powershell command about virtual machine just query from hyper-v and just you send message through powershell to os ([just windows](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kebab/archive/2014/06/24/sending-messages-and-commands-to-a-hyper-v-virtual-machine-guest-os-using-the-kvp-exchange.aspx))you can see all cmd-let for Hyper-v module in [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848559.aspx),but you have get more information from xml file of machine see [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/virtual_pc_guy/archive/2010/03/10/understanding-where-your-virtual-machine-files-are-hyper-v.aspx)
also you can send command through powershell to [vm machine](http://www.altaro.com/hyper-v/using-powershell-manage-utilize-hyper-v-integration-services-server-2012-r2/)

```
Invoke-Command –ComputerName <Hostname> -Credential <Domain>\<Username> -Scriptblock {[System.Environment]::OSVersion.Version}
```

Comment: do i have to run this command through every vm..?? i mean it will take much more time.. and do u agree with checking version to differentiate windows and linux.. are you aware of any other way..?

Comment: @user2806673 i tell u in my answer this send command just for windows not any os , for check os see contain of xml file for hyper-v machine please read complete my answer [xml](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/virtual_pc_guy/archive/2010/03/10/understanding-where-your-virtual-machine-files-are-hyper-v.aspx)

Comment: invoke command didnt worked on linux. to execute {[System.Environment]::OSVersion.Version}

Comment: If read 1 time my post I said **through powershell to os (just windows)** when u send this and get response you understand that it is a windows otherwise when u get error you find out the os is Linux